# how to save and get selected item id list with add_meta_box

Tags: metabox

hi all i need create to metabox in page for the footer and header posttypes i created, in this code i tried for this but i cant save selected item and retrive id selected item in the frontend.

```
function wpdocs_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box-id', __( 'header', 'textdomain' ),'wpdocs_my_display_callback', 'page', 'normal' , 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpdocs_register_meta_boxes' );
 

function wpdocs_my_display_callback() {

    ?>

    <select name="count" id="selectId" >
    <?php  

    $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'header')); 
    while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
       <option id="selection" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile;
    die()
    ?>
    </select>
   <?php 
}
 

function wpdocs_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {


    if (isset($_POST['selectId'])) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'selectId', $_POST['selectId']);
    }


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpdocs_save_meta_box' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code.

First,

The name of the select field is not the same as you are trying to save using the global variable `$_POST`. You are saving `$_POST['selectId']` data but it does not exist in your meta box. You named the select field as "count" but trying to get value using `"selectId"` key.

Second,

You need to get the saved value and use it to compare with the select field value to be selected.

Your `wpdocs_my_display_callback` function will be like this to set the selected value.

```php
    function wpdocs_my_display_callback()
    {
        global $post;
        $saved_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'selectId', true);
    ?>
    
        <select name="selectId" id="selectId">
            <?php
    
            $posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'header'));
            while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                <option <?php selected($saved_value, get_the_ID()); ?> id="selection" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile;
            // die()
            ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
```

I think it will work for now.